# What's the probability that the news station predicted the outcome incorrectly?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, sampling

I wrote this problem for a high school statistics activity on the sampling distribution of sample proportions. When I sat down to write solutions I realized that it was maybe too confusing to assign, and now I'm not confident in my solution. Is my attempt a reasonable solution?

**Question:**

Suppose that during an election, a news agency that conducts a poll of 105 random voters and finds a sample proportion of 54% in support of a ballot measure that requires a majority to pass. The agency publishes a prediction that the measure will pass. How likely is it that the news agency is incorrect?

**Attempt at a solution:**

Let $n = 105,$ $\hat p=0.54$, and we use $ \sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{0.25}{105}} = 0.0488$ as the worst case, since $p$ is unknown.

Notice that 0.54 is $0.4 = 0.82 \sigma$ away from $0.50$, which is the threshold for a “majority”. The proportion of samples with sample proportions that have z-scores within $.82$ of $0$ is $normalcdf(-.82,.82,0,1) = 0.587$.

So, 58.7% of random samples will have sample proportions within $.82\sigma$ of the true population proportion. In order for the news agency to be incorrect, $ \hat p=0.54$ must be more than $0.82 \sigma$ above the true population proportion.

Because of the symmetry of the normal distribution, at most $(1 - 0.587)/2 = 20.65\%$ of random samples will be at least this far above true proportion. So, since the sample was random, there is at most a $20.65\%$ chance that the outcome of the election will disagree with the news agency’s prediction.

Comment: It would be appropriate to ask for a 95% confidence interval for the true proportion $p$ of the population in favor of the proposition. It would be appropriate to test $H_0: p=1/2$ against $H_a: p > 1/2$ at the 5% level, and do ask for the P-value of the test. Unless this is a problem in Bayesian statistics it is not appropriate to ask for the _probability_ that the station acted appropriately.

Comment: @BruceET I appreciate your comment, and I agree that a confidence interval would be appropriate, but I haven't introduced it yet. My students have been getting comfortable using the normal model to describe the sampling distribution of sample proportions (as a description of the proportion of random samples, not probability, formally), we will end the semester with confidence intervals and hypothesis tests for a sample proportion. The assignment this question is on is meant to lead them into those ideas so that they seem natural when they are formally defined.

Answer (score 1):

Printout from a recent release of Minitab statistical software. I entered 57 Yes's out of the 105 interviews,
this gives the estimate $\hat p = 542857,$ not $\hat p = 0.54.$ Why not give the actual number in favor?

```
Test and CI for One Proportion 

Test of p = 0.5 vs p > 0.5


                                              Exact
Sample   X    N  Sample p  95% Lower Bound  P-Value
1       57  105  0.542857         0.457999    0.218
```

P-value exceeds 5% = 0.05, so you cannot reject $H_0.$
The actual percentage of the population in favor might be as low as 45.8%.

With so small a sample, it is not surprising
that the poll does not give useful results.
In election polling, it takes about $n=600$ subjects to get minimally useful results. This sample size gives a 2-sided confidence
interval with a margin of sampling error about $\pm 4\%.$ (For $\pm 2\%$ use $n = 2500.)$